# make me idempotent!

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, finite-semigroups

$T_n$ be the full transformation semigroup on $X_n= \{1, 2, \cdots , n\}$.

$D_r =\{\alpha \in T_n: |im(\alpha)|=r\}$.

$E(D_r)$ is the set of all idempotents of semigroup $T_n$.

$shift(\alpha)=\{x: x\alpha\neq x\}$

We know that $\alpha \in T_n$ is idempotent $\iff$ $x\alpha=x$ for all $x\in im(\alpha)$.

I wonder product of idempotents. For example;
$\alpha =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 &  4 \\
1 & 2 & 2 &  1
\end{pmatrix}$, $\beta=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 &  4 \\
3 & 4 & 3 &  4
\end{pmatrix} \in E(D_2)$, but $\alpha\beta=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 &  4 \\
3 & 4 & 4 &  3
\end{pmatrix}$ is not idempotent.

$\textbf{Question:}$ Let $\alpha_0, \alpha_1\cdots, \alpha_k\in E(D_r)$ and $shift(\alpha_i)\cap shift(\alpha_j)=\emptyset, 0\leq i\neq j\leq k $.

Under which condition the product $\alpha_0\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_k$ becomes idempotent ?

Comment: Why would you think there should be a reasonable answer to your question? The condition $shift(\alpha_i)\cap shift(\alpha_j)=\emptyset$ does not seem to give any useful information to decide whether the product is idempotent or not.

Comment: J.-E. Pin I can't find  good answer. Attracting my attention
the product seem quasi  idempotent.